# How can I tell if my app upgrade from angular 2 to angular 4 was successful?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, npm

I had a .NET WebAPI application that was using angular 2 with and decided to upgrade to angular 4.

I went through somthing like the following in the cmd for my project directory (along with a few iterations of installing missing dependencies):

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

I recently went through the CLI to update my angular app from angular 2 to angular 4. Now, is there a way for me to confirm that my application is actually using angular 4 rather than 2?

If i type in "ng --version" into the cmd line for the directly that has my project, then I get the following result:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.5
@angular/common: 4.2.5
@angular/compiler: 4.2.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.5
@angular/core: 4.2.5
@angular/forms: 4.2.5
@angular/http: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-server: 4.2.5
@angular/router: 4.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
```

if i run my application then and look at the brower developer tools i see this in the DOM explorer:

```
<html>
<body>
    <my-app ng-version="2.4.8" _nghost-vrp-0=""> 
... other stuff that isn't important
</html>
</body>
```

so it looks like my app says ng-version ="2.4.8" but does my CLI say differently? Did i successfully upgrade, and if so, why does the DOM in the browser developer tools say differently?

Again, this is a .NET WebAPI application that was using angular 2 with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try some of the hot new angular4 features and see if it works, or see if it compiles with a ng build --prod --aot

```
 <div *ngIf="userList | async as users; else loading">
  <user-profile *ngFor="let user of users; count as count; index as i" [user]="user">
User {{i}} of {{count}}
  </user-profile>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

Comment: is that code supposed to work as-is in the HTML with nothing added to the component? It does not work :Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

Can't bind to 'user' since it isn't a known property of 'user-profile'...

im guessing that means i dont have angular 4 on the app?

Comment: You need the correct objects bound to the ts file. This is just the sample angular gives about the new syntax of ngIfs and ngFors

Comment: do you have a link to that documentation? I would like to go through it and try your suggestion

Comment: Sure thing, it's pulled from here http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html
You can do an easier angular 4 sample in the documentation somewhere. the ngFor stuff is really cool. Here is a decent tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5G-9tJTces

Comment: looks like my app didnt update even after I added the attributes to the ts files. any idea on what I could be missing?

Comment: Have you tried the npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save from the same page I linked above? I never used angular with .net but I don't think it would interfere

Comment: turns out my app was upgraded to angular 4. It was an issue of not clearing my cache, so it was showing up as 2.x instead of 4.x. Now it correctly shows the right version and the Angular 4 syntax works fine.

Comment: Ah good to hear! Sorry I should of trouble shot the firstly. I can't tell you how many times I got burnt by forgetting to toggle ng serve's

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my app was upgraded to angular 4. It was an issue of not clearing my cache, so it was showing up as 2.x instead of 4.x. Now it correctly shows the right version and the Angular 4 syntax works fine.